# Ruby on Rails: gem not found even though it is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

I get this error trying to run any Ultrasphinx rake commands (under Linux terminal) such as rake ultrasphinx:configure :

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- echoe
/var/www/gitorious/vendor/plugins/ultrasphinx/Rakefile:2:in `require'
/var/www/gitorious/vendor/plugins/ultrasphinx/Rakefile:2
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2359:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2359:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:1993:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2044:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:1992:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:1976:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2044:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:1974:in `run'
/usr/bin/rake:28
```

I gather this means echoe gem is not installed. But if I run "gem list --local" it shows that the echoe gem is installed. What could be the problem here and how can I debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to upgrade the echoe version?

```
sudo gem update echoe
```

It's strange. All ultrasphinx task are properly defined in a .rake file that should be loaded by Rails without passing through the plugin Rakefile file.

Also make sure you run

```
rake ultrasphinx:configure
```

from the project root and not the plugin root.

Comment: Ah, that solved the echoe problem, now I get a different problem which is probably related to the project (Gitorious) which I have to figure out next.

The directory thing was exactly the correct answer!